# Can't connect to a DataSnap server in another city

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I create a server and client using DataSnap in a Delphi app.

In the server, I have `TFDConnection`, `TFDQuery`, and `TDataSetProvider`.

In the client, I use `TSQLConnection`, `TDSProviderConnection`, `TClientDataSet`, and `TDataSource` to show data in a `TDBGrid`.

I open a port in the modem firewall and in Windows Firewall. My client is in New York and my server is in Chicago. I want to connect my client to my server.

In the client `TSQLConnection` Params, I set the host name to my IP address in Chicago, but when I run my client, it can't connect to my server.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: This sounds more like a network configuration issue rather than a coding issue. Try asking on [sf]. That being said, you did not say whether the client and server are on the same network or on different networks. In the former case, a VPN can be used, in which case there should be no boundary for not being able to connect. In the latter case, you would need to setup port forwarding on the server's router, did you do that yet?

Comment: Program use TCP connection, so it does not care server on PC in same room or on PC in another part of world. It's definitely problem with network configuration.

Comment: @shsh Why are you asking and not OP? Multiple accounts for one person are not allowed on this website.

Comment: @Oleksandr Morozevych how fix this ?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau how network configuration for client server datasnap ?

Comment: my quetion is how we can find or setup setting to find server ?

Comment: in localhost i have not problem but when i want connect client in other place server. cant find server i add port and ip address to my modem firewall and in firewall windows i add this but client cant find server

Comment: When entering server IP in your client which IP are you using? Perhaps you are using servers LAN IP instead of WAN IP. LAN IP is local network address of a computer while WAN IP is IP address with which the computer is seen to the rest of the Internet. You need to use WAN IP unless booth of the computers belong to the same VPN network in which case using of LAN IP might also be possible.

Comment: @SilverWarior when i use WAN IP show me eror : exception EldSocketEror in module myfirstClient.exe at00315464 Socket Eror #10060 connection time out.how fix it? i add port and wan ip in firewall modem and add port in firewall windows.

Comment: @user23198637 as I already told you earlier, if you are not using a VPN to connect the machines, then you must configure the server's network router to open a WAN IP/port and then **port forward** that WAN IP/port to the server's LAN IP/port, only then can the client connect to the WAN IP/port to reach the server. This is NOT a coding issue, it is a network admin issue.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau i was add port and wanip into firewall modem. but how can then port forward that WAN IP/port to the server's LAN IP/port??

Comment: @user23198637 you need to consult your modem/router's documentation for that. It is not enough to just open the port if it doesn't actually go anywhere.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau what i do to configure modem? my modem is tplink TD-W8960N

Comment: @user23198637 per the [TD-W8960N documentation](https://static.tp-link.com/res/down/doc/TD-W8960N(EU)_V7_UG.pdf), use the "Virtual Servers" setup to forward inbound traffic from the router's WAN IP/port to the DataSnap server's LAN IP/port.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau i read TD-W8960N documentation and i set up in nat ipaddress and port .in virtual server same ip was added i mean ipaddress and port in nat is equal with virtual server but my client cant connect in to server with wan ip what i do?

Comment: @user23198637 StackOverflow is not a discussion forum. This has gone beyond the scope of this post, and of StackOverflow in general. Please direct any further questions regarding your network config to [sf]. If you have an actual coding question, come back to StackOverflow.